# Applying a Function to an Array in Definable Dimensions

Tags: r, arrays, function, for-loop

I am working with arrays generated from a .tif file of RGB values. I'm attempting to apply a custom function over the entirety of the array in 10 x 10 increments by using a for-loop to change the indexing of the arrays in said function, which should give me a scalar. The array dimensions are 1040 x 1388.

```
p.count<-function(x, y){
for (i in 1:seq(1,nrow(x),10))
  for  (j in 1:seq(1,ncol(x),4))
  FUNCTION(x
           [1:i,1:j,],
           y
           [1:i,1:j,]
           )}
```

Where FUNCTION is my custom function, and x and y are the two arrays.

edit: when running the code I get an error:

> Error in is.numeric(x) || is.complex(x) : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to improve your question.

Comment: `seq()` already defines a sequence, you probably don't need the initial `1:`, keep just `seq`.

Comment: Removing the ```1:``` doesn't seem to help the code.